# How to inject service to validator constraint interface in nestjs using class-validator?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to inject my users service into my validator constraint interface but it doesn't seem to work:

```
import { ValidatorConstraintInterface, ValidatorConstraint, ValidationArguments, registerDecorator, ValidationOptions } from "class-validator";
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
export class IsEmailAlreadyInUseConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {
        console.log(this.usersService);
    }
    validate(email: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
        return this.usersService.findUserByEmail(email).then(user => {
             if (user) return false;
             return true;
        });
        return false;
    }

}
```

But, as usersService is logged null, I can't access its methods.

Any insight on this matter?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For those who might be suffering from this issue:

class-validator requires you to use service containers if you want to inject dependencies into your custom validator constraint classes. From: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#using-service-container

```
import {useContainer, Validator} from "class-validator";

// do this somewhere in the global application level:
useContainer(Container);
```

So that we need to add the user container function into the global application level.

**1. Add the following code to your main.ts bootstrap function after app declaration:**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });
...}
```

The {fallbackOnErrors: true} is required, because Nest throw Exception when DI doesn't have required class.

**2. Add Injectable() to your constraint:**

```
import {ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface} from 'class-validator';
import {UsersService} from './user.service';
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'isUserAlreadyExist', async: true })
@Injectable() // this is needed in order to the class be injected into the module
export class IsUserAlreadyExist implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    constructor(protected readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

    async validate(text: string) {
        const user = await this.usersService.findOne({
            email: text
        });
        return !user;
    }
}
```

**3. Inject the constraint into your module as a provider and make sure that the service you intend to inject into your constraint are also available to a module level:**

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersController } from './user.controller';
import { UsersService } from './user.service';
import { IsUserAlreadyExist } from './user.validator';

@Module({
    controllers: [UsersController],
    providers: [IsUserAlreadyExist, UsersService],
    imports: [],
    exports: []
})
export class UserModule {
}
```

Comment: This is a great anwer, however, I would love to see how you would inject the container inside app.module.ts instead of main.ts, since when running tests main.ts does not get triggered.

Comment: I couldn't figure out step 3 - you answer just saved me a whole lot of nerves :)

Comment: @FooBar you can inject ModuleRef into the module(`constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}`) and then call useContainer in onModuleInit(`onModuleInit() { useContainer(this.moduleRef, { fallbackOnErrors: true }); }`)

Comment: When using the repository pattern injecting the repository would work the same way, refer to this [article](https://dev.to/avantar/custom-validation-with-database-in-nestjs-gao)

Comment: @juraj Unfortunately, this does not work for me

Answer (score 8):

By the way, this doesn't work in e2e test. This is the way how I get it running.

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();
    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();

    app.useGlobalPipes(GetValidationPipe());
    useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });
    await app.init();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to update `class-validator`'s container to use the Nest application to allow for Dependency Injection everywhere. [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/528#issuecomment-382330137) goes through how to do it and some struggles people have faced with it.

Quick fix without reading the link:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
  useContainer(app, { fallback: true });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

When doing this, make sure you also register your validators as you normally would any nest `@Injectable()`

Comment: thanks for sharing. `useContainer(app, { fallback: true });` what is its task?

Comment: can we use useContainer on the AppModule?

Comment: @kadiro not to my knowledge, because we need to pass `app`, the configured application, to the `useContainer` method